# Como criar um array com cores de uma roleta?

Tags: c

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{

    char cor[35]; // declarar vetor para receber nome das cores
    int numeros[35] = {0}; // declarar vetor para receber o numero respectivo das cores
    int i = 0;
    int entrada;

    for (i = 0; i <= 35; i++)
    {
        printf(" DIGITE O NUMERO: ");// atribuir os valores, neste caso de 0 a 35
        scanf("%i", &numeros[i]);
        i = i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 35; i++)
    {
        printf(" DIGITE AS CORES EM SEQUENCIA: ");// atribuir as cores com os numeros respectivos em sequencia de 0 a 35
        scanf("%c"&cor[i]);
        i = i++;
    }

    i = 0;

    printf(" DIGITE QUAL NUMERO VOCE DESEJA: ");// entrada do usuario
    scanf("%i"&entrada);
}
```

Já fiz algo assim só que não sei mais como prosseguir.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Esse código não parece ter nada a ver com o enunciado. Escrevi um código de acordo com o que entendi.

Se ele é grande ou não, par ou ímpar dá para descobrir por verificação normal usando comparação é matemática pura.

As cores precisam ter um padrão indicando como cada número é representado. Eu criei um *array* com um caractere representando a cor na posição de cada número. O *array* precisa ter 37 posições porque vai do 0 ao 36. O 0 é verde, por isso merece tratamento a diferenciação. Não segui as cores que estão na imagem da roleta. Se isto for importante, é só mudar a ordem disposta no *array*, cada caractere é um posição. Um *array* que é uma sequência de caracteres é uma *string* então ficou mais fácil declarar assim. Estritamente há um ligeiro problema técnico em fazer isto, mas não vai afetar o funcionamento em algo tão simples.

Depois de digitado o valor é pega a posição do *array* de acordo com o digitado para escolher a cor e decidir o que escrever. Depois pega o resto de 2 para saber se é par e verifica se o número é maior que 18, mas não sei se este critério está correto.

Não tem no enunciado, mas verifiquei se foi digitado um valor inválido, até porque sem isto, daria problema no código.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char cor[37] = "0PVPPVPVVVPPVPVVVVPVPPVPVPPVPVPVPPVPV";
    int entrada;
    printf("Qual é o número? ");
    scanf("%i", &entrada);
    if (entrada < 0 || entrada > 36) { 
        printf("Valor inválido");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\nO número é %d, é %s", entrada, cor[entrada] == 'V' ? "vermelho" : cor[entrada] == 'P'
                                                                 ? "preto" : "verde");
    printf(", %s", entrada > 18 ? "grande" : "pequeno");
    printf(", %s", entrada % 2 == 0 ? "par" : "ímpar");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wmoc0f). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pfdtzcvu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ChangeState.c).

Portanto o código era bem mais simples do que estava sendo tentado. Começo por interpretar o texto corretamente. Depois ter um entendimento matemático das coisas. Na hora de codificar o mínimo que precisa saber é a sintaxe das coisas. O código escrito tinha diversos problemas e nem compilava. Mesmo que a lógica fosse esta descrita ano código, ainda tem outros problemas de lógica além dos erros de sintaxe.

Comment: Fazendo os deveres de casa? ;)